# How to create a NSMenu Instance with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nsstatusbar

I have look made some search, however could not find any information. Question is pretty straight-forward. I don't know if it is possible, but, in this [link](http://footle.org/WeatherBar/) they could create a `NSMenu` item via `xib` files. So I thought maybe it is possible to create `NSMenu` using `SwiftUI` as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the NSMenu?

Comment: :) I was trying to make NSMenu with using SwiftUI. I found a solution creating NSMenuItem using NSHostingController that initiates a SwiftUI class. Now I am just waiting for another way if there is any.

Comment: Dude if u found an answer on ur question can u publish it? Do u understand that there is more than u who trying to find a solution.

Comment: Not directly but you can check my prev comment @NyanNyan

Comment: Still if you request futher explanation I will do it within 24 hours. @NyanNyan

Comment: It will be pleasure if u publish a short answer, thank you)

Answer (score -1):

The answer for me was wrapping my desired `SwiftUI` view code using `NSHostingView`. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nshostingview)

I can share the snippet, however it may take some time because I do not have laptop containing the project with me.